# Absolute phrase with adjective?

Tags: adjectives, absolute-clauses, absolute-construction

So I've recently learned about absolute phrase and wondering if we can use it with adjective like:

> Lanterns hang from the branches, the night sky **visible** through the spaces between the leaves.

Is that correct?

Comment: Have you searched for examples of such phrases? If you do, you should see what kinds of phrases can modify the nominal. In addition to "absolute phrase", you may want to search for "nominative absolute" and "absolute clause".

Comment: @MarclnManhattan, not really. Most of them use past or present participle. Which is why I am confused about the matter.

Comment: It's not so much "an absolute clause being used with an adjective" as a verbless absolute clause.

Comment: @RifpanP Yes, phrases headed by present and past participles are very common in these constructions, but those headed by adjectives can modify the nominal as well. I'm surprised that you didn't find any. Your sentence is certainly correct.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It's actually a clause, not a phrase. To say it is headed by an adjective is misleading since that implies it is an adjective phrase, which it isn't. It's actually a verbless clause, as I explained in my answer. Further, there's no modification involved. Absolute clauses are not modifiers but supplements that are not integrated into the structure of the clause.

Comment: @BillJ I understand that it is a clause in your interpretation. It is not in mine. Also, I never claimed that the overall absolute phrase was a modifier.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It has a subject-predicate structure and hence is a clause. See here: [link](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/absolute-clause#:~:text=An%20adverbial%20CLAUSE%20that%20has,the%20subject%20is%20the%20dinner.) and here [link](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800879.001.0001/acref-9780192800879-e-8). Your arguments are not well-informed, indeed they are misleading.

Comment: @BillJ You do realize that there is more than one definition of "clause", right? We've had this discussion before, and you seem to think that other people's interpretations are wrong simply because they're not your interpretation, while I believe that multiple interpretations may be valid. Can we leave it at that so we don't clog up another comment section?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan The links I provided seem authoritative enough.  I base my definitions on those that are widely accepted by grammarians. The status of an expression as a clause is based on its grammatical structure (as opposed to its semantics). The occurrence of a subject plus a predicate is generally sufficient to identify it as a clause. In particular, the head of a clause is always a verb phrase, whose head is always a verb. There are other tests. I'm sorry, but your comments and answers are often misguided and not well-informed.

Comment: @BillJ If you want "authoritative" links, here is one where the verb must be finite: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clause?q=clause_1. And of course I can provide many, many others. Please don't call what I'm saying "misguided and not well-informed", because I'm well informed about what you're saying and am using a definition of "clause" that I believe is appropriate for ELL. If you prefer another definition, fine, then it's enough just to say that.

Comment: The link you provide is contradictory. First it defines a clause as "a group of words, consisting of a subject and a finite form of a verb" and then lower down it talks of non-finite clauses! The requirement for a clause to have a finite verb went out the window many years ago. It is widely accepted nowadays throughout the world of grammar, including ELL, that there is no such requirement. You really should know that, see here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause). Notice that Wiki refers to the examples it cites as clauses, not phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Lanterns hang from the branches,* [*the night sky visible through the*
> *spaces between the leaves*].

Preliminary point: absolutes are not modifiers but supplements, loosely attached expressions presenting supplementary non-integrated content.

They consist of non-finite clauses that contain a subject and have no syntactic link to the main clause.

Your example has no verb, and thus it's a verbless clause, though I would still call it an absolute construction; more specifically it's the verbless analogue of:

> *Lanterns hang from the branches,* [*the night sky being visible through the*
> *spaces between the leaves*].

Incidentally, the verb in the absolute clause can also be a past participle, as in

> *That done,* [*she walked off without saying another word*.]

Answer (score 0):

This will be a long answer, but I hope that it will also be useful for others who have similar questions.

A nominative absolute (that is the term that I prefer, although there are certainly others) has the following characteristics:

1. It consists of a nominal phrase modified by a following adjectival phrase.
2. It is not integrated into the syntax of the neighboring text. (It may be considered a kind of "disjunct".)

You asked about whether the adjectival phrase could be headed by an adjective, and the answer is yes. In fact, most kinds of phrases that function adjectivally can be used. Let's consider several kinds of heads.

Past participle:

> Our car **broken**, we had to cancel the rest of the trip.

Present participle:

> The car **running smoothly once more**, we resumed our trip.

Adjective:

> Its gas tank **empty**, the car finally came to a stop.

Preposition:

> Its radiator **on the fritz**, we abandoned the car.

Full infinitive:

> Our destination **yet to be seen**, we despaired of ever arriving.

The following are rare and perhaps questionable grammatically, although I know of no rule prohibiting them.

Possessive case noun:

> The car **John's**, I had no right to question what he wanted to do with it.

Possessive case pronoun:

> The car **his**, John had every right to decide what he wanted to do with it.

The only such kind of phrase (i.e., one that can function adjectivally) that can not normally be used as the second element in a nominative absolute phrase, as far I'm aware, is an attributive nominal. (Attributive nominals typically precede their referents.) You might construct something like this, although I probably wouldn't consider it grammatical:

> ?The car's weight **1000 pounds**, we didn't want to push it to our destination.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say on two counts: First, the term 'absolute' means that the clause (not phrase) has no syntactic link to the main clause, thus it can hardly be claimed to be adjectival. Second, regarding your point 1. there is no requirement for it to be followed by an adjective phrase. Consider these examples:  _**That done**, she walked off without saying another word._ /  _**His hands gripping the door**, he let out a volley of curses_. In neither of those examples is there an adjective in the absolute clause.

Comment: @BillJ I think there are misunderstandings in both of your points. Regarding your first point, I never claimed that the overall phrase was adjectival. (I said it could be considered a disjunct.) Regarding your second, I never said that there was an adjective in the absolute clause; I said "adjectival phrase", which is different.

Comment: Your statement that "a nominative absolute consists of a nominal phrase modified by a following adjectival phrase ..." is simply untrue. As I said (with examples) there is no such requirement. The head of an adjective phrase is an adjective. The absence of an adjective means there's no adjective phrase.

Comment: @BillJ I don't know why you keep trying to criticize my use of the term "adjective phrase" when I haven't used that term once in my answer or any of the comments. "Adjective" is not the same as "adjectival" (just as "verb" is not the same as "verbal", e.g.).

Comment: I think you did. Look at point 1. in your answer, where you say "It consists of a nominal phrase modified by a following **adjectival phrase**". In any case, that statement is also wrong because there is no such requirement, as the examples I gave in my first comment show.

Comment: You keep equating "adjective phrase" with "adjectival phrase". I don't know why. As for your two examples, I dealt with phrases headed by past participles (like "done") and phrases headed by present participles (like "gripping the door") in my answer. I really don't know what else to say. I'm done with this thread.

Comment: @BillJ (Forgot tag in my previous comment. I'm still done with this.)